# Student - challenge converting db.execute statement into proper SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am a newbie taking my first course in Python/SQL/html

When I issue the following statement:

```
db.execute ("UPDATE portfolio SET qty = :qty", \
        WHERE username = :username AND symbol = :symbol", qty=qty, username=username, symbol=symbol)
```

I receive the following error:

> RuntimeError: unused values (username, symbol)

This other statement works fine:

```
 db.execute ("INSERT INTO history (username, transtype, symbol, stockname, price, qty, extprice) \
      VALUES (:username,  :transtype, :symbol, :stockname, :price, :qty, :extprice)", \
      username=username, transtype=transtype, symbol=symbol, stockname=stockname,  \
      price=price, qty=qty, extprice=extprice)
```

I'm not sure what the proper syntax should be to get the variables to resolve in the first db.execute.  Any help would be appreciated.   Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Your quotes aren't balanced properly in the first example.

Comment: You should get a syntax error, so you probably didn't copy it correctly. Post the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this Works

```
db.execute ("INSERT INTO history (username, transtype, symbol, stockname, price, qty, extprice) \
      VALUES (:username,  :transtype, :symbol, :stockname, :price, :qty, :extprice)", \
      username=username, transtype=transtype, symbol=symbol, stockname=stockname,  \
      price=price, qty=qty, extprice=extprice)
```

And if the following doesn't

```
db.execute ("UPDATE portfolio SET qty = :qty", \
        WHERE username = :username AND symbol = :symbol", qty=qty, username=username, symbol=symbol)
```

You should notice that the SQL statement portion and the assigning values to the variables has to be separated.
So the correct code has to be:

```
db.execute ("UPDATE portfolio SET qty = :qty \
        WHERE username = :username AND symbol = :symbol", qty=qty, username=username, symbol=symbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra quote there.

Try changing the first line to db.execute ("UPDATE portfolio SET qty = :qty, \